# Picker preview and how can I change it

Tags: swift

I'm learning currently Swift and SwiftUI. I am trying to copy Xiaomi currency converter at IOS for practice. There is a little flaw in the code and I have no idea how to fix it:

```
Picker("", selection: $pickerSelection1) {
                ForEach(0..<self.api.currencyCode1.count) {
                    let currency = api.currencyCode1[$0]
                    Text("\(api.txt[$0])" + " " + currency)
                    }
                }
            .id(UUID())
            .labelsHidden()
            .padding(.leading)
```

This code will show you the full name while you will be watching at the picker(for example "American Dollar USD").

Is it possible to show just a currency code? (USD)

Comment: It's not clear from the code that you've included what `api` is or what `currencyCode1` or `txt` contains. Can you include a [mre]?

Comment: Just a guess, `Text(api.currencyCode1[$0])`